# Recover deleted PostgreSQL config files

Tags: postgresql, docker, configuration, recover

I was trying to delete `pg_log` folder (it was huge 3Gib) But i accidentally remove everything in data folder (by rm ./*):

[image]

Now all of the .conf files removed from data folder and i receiving this error in the log:

"Data page checksums are disabled"

The postgres was made by docker through [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/tags?page=1&name=15-alpine) (15-alpine)

I didn't touch any config files there.

Where can i find the default postgres config files? I think i can make it back to work by restoring the .conf files.

Comment: just run another postgres container using docker image and copy internals of that files

Comment: @num8er I have this folder on docker volume, Where can i find the original config files? Somewhere like potgres github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to recover default config files using Docker image.

1. Pull docker image for Postrgres:

```bash
docker pull postgres:15-alpine
```

2. Run container:

```bash
docker run -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:15-alpine
```

3. Keep current terminal open and open new terminal
4. Connect to shell in docker container:

```bash
docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS      NAMES
aee1237294b8   postgres:15-alpine3.17   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   5432/tcp   naughty_knuth
```

copy container id from `docker ps` result and execute shell command:

```bash
docker exec -it aee1237294b8 bash
```

5. Go to data folder and archive it:

```bash
cd /var/lib/postgresql/data/
tar -zcf pgdata.tar.gz *
```

6. Exit docker container shell:

```bash
exit
```

7. Copy archive from docker container:

```bash
docker cp aee1237294b8:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata.tar.gz ~/Downloads/pgdata.tar.gz
```

as result I've downloaded config from `postgres:15-alpine`

grab it from here: https://anarjafarov.me/pg.conf.zip

and watch video instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgHtvwbQJDE